Weight function given polynomial basis
Consider the following polynomial inner product:
$$ (p,q)=\int_{-1}^{1} p(x) g(x) w(x) dx $$
It is well known that the polynomials of an orthogonal basis have simple roots, regardless of the weight function $w(x)$.
This implies that a weight function cannot be chosen such that the power basis $B=\{1,x,x^2,x^3,\dots\}$ is orthogonal.
However, given a group of simple-rooted polynomials (whose roots lie on the domain $[-1,1]$), is there always a weight function that deems the group orthogonal?
What other conditions must the group satisfy for this function to exist (other than simple-rootedness)?
Can we always find this function if we already know the basis? Is so, how?
Thank you very much.

The claim does not hold. The roots of two consecutive polynomials must interlace. Still this additional condition is not sufficient. Indeed WLOG we may assume that the polynomials are monic, i.e. that the leading coefficients are equal $1.$   The orthogonal polynomials satisfy the three term recurrence relation of the form page 4, (13)$$xp_n=p_{n+1}+a_np_n+ b_np_{n-1}$$ where $b_n>0$ for $n\ge 1.$ Thus the polynomials $xp_n,$ $p_{n+1},$ $p_n$ and $p_{n-1}$ are linearly dependent. Let $p_0=1,$ $ p_1=x,$ $p_2=x^2-1$ and $$p_3=x(x-2)(x+3)=x^3+x^2-6x$$Then $$xp_2-p_3=-x^2+5x=-p_2+5p_1+5p_0$$ The last representation is unique, as the polynomials $p_0,p_1,p_2$ and $p_3$ form a linear basis of the space of polynomials of the third degree. The recurrence relation mentioned above is not satisfied for $n=2.$
In order to bring the roots into the interval $(-1,1)$ it suffices to consider the rescaled polynomials $q_n(x)=p_n(4x).$ The coefficients in the last formula when we subsitute $q_n(x)$ will be divided by $4.$ Thus the polynomials $q_n$ do not satisfy the three term recurrence relation.

so, does it mean that if the basis satisfies the 3-term recurrence for some valid an and bn, then a wight function must exist for that basis?

Yes, look up the Favard theorem
